# R: loop over result of tend test to save to frame and access the file name

Tags: r, loops, filenames

I have two problems.

1)
I'm preparing a script with multiple calculations of the trend with M-K test over different cases. Then I'm saving chosen parameters to a df. I'm collecting all results in one df. I've written everything "by hand" to see if I'm correct, and now I'm looking a way to optimize my code, probably by applying a few loops. How do I make these calculations in a loop:

```
#calculate trends in 10-cases series (and later on fixed reach series):
mk10_1 <- mk.test(db$sum[1:10])
mk10_2 <- mk.test(db$sum[11:20])
mk10_3 <- mk.test(db$sum[21:30])
mk10_4 <- mk.test(db$sum[31:40])
mk10_5 <- mk.test(db$sum[41:50])
mk10_6 <- mk.test(db$sum[51:60])

#add the result to result df mktests:
mktests$mk10_1 <- c(mk10_1$statistic, mk10_1$p.value, mk10_1$estimates[1], mk10_1$estimates[2], mk10_1$estimates[3])
mktests$mk10_2 <- c(mk10_2$statistic, mk10_2$p.value, mk10_2$estimates[1], mk10_2$estimates[2], mk10_2$estimates[3])
mktests$mk10_3 <- c(mk10_3$statistic, mk10_3$p.value, mk10_3$estimates[1], mk10_3$estimates[2], mk10_3$estimates[3])
mktests$mk10_4 <- c(mk10_4$statistic, mk10_4$p.value, mk10_4$estimates[1], mk10_4$estimates[2], mk10_4$estimates[3])
mktests$mk10_5 <- c(mk10_5$statistic, mk10_5$p.value, mk10_5$estimates[1], mk10_5$estimates[2], mk10_5$estimates[3])
mktests$mk10_6 <- c(mk10_6$statistic, mk10_6$p.value, mk10_6$estimates[1], mk10_6$estimates[2], mk10_6$estimates[3])
```

I have around 60 cases with few ways of selecting the result: like start with 1 + every 2 <- but this I'll figure out based on the solution of above problem.

2)
Once the entire script is ready I want to loop it through files in a folder, so naturally I need a way to access the read.csv file name store in and then use it to write a result.
When I'm loading the data, I'm using this form (file name is a code that relates to database):

```
#load data from csv file
data_raw <- read.csv("D:/149180020.csv", header=FALSE, sep=";")
```

how do I get the number to later save the results to files:

```
149180020_mk.csv
149180020_acf.csv
```

Thanks in advance for the answers!
Chris

---

Edit:
about libraries, in this project I use a lot of them, to be precise:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
library(e1071)
library(lubridate)
library(Kendall)
library(trend)
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
```

the mk.trend comes from trend pack.

the data used for this:

for trend analysis: db (head of 68 rows):

```
    year      sum
   <int>     <dbl>
1   1951 10471680
2   1952 19065888
3   1953 29909088
4   1954 94230000
5   1955 16364592
6   1956  1225152
```

when loading the file: data_raw:

```
         id     name   year   month   day value
1 149180020     loc1   1951       1     1  38.1
2 149180020     loc1   1951       1     2  56.4
3 149180020     loc1   1951       1     3  52.3
4 149180020     loc1   1951       1     4  52.3
5 149180020     loc1   1951       1     5  60.9
6 149180020     loc1   1951       1     6  55.3
```

the id in the table corresponds to id in the file names.

Here is the result of m-k trend analysis for the given above examples, after loading to mk_result table:

```
                z    p-value   S      varS         tau
mk10_1 -0.3577709 0.72051479  -5 125.00000 -0.11111111
mk10_2 -1.7888544 0.07363827 -21 125.00000 -0.46666667
mk10_3 -1.8927875 0.05838613 -18  80.66667 -0.54772256
mk10_4  1.0820036 0.27925095  13 123.00000  0.29553088
mk10_5 -2.0397202 0.04137820 -23 116.33333 -0.54902140
mk10_6 -0.2694080 0.78761577  -4 124.00000 -0.08989331
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited the topic to add libraries and data

Comment: FYI: When you load the "tidyverse" package you are automatically loading "ggplot2", "dplyr", "tidyr" and others,  thus save keystrokes and avoid attempting to load them again. See: https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/

Comment: good to know, thanks!